# Run a bat file on specific date

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to know how I can run a .bat file on a specific date.

Sample code:

```
if "%date%" == " Wed 08/04/2021" 
    start "" "C:\Users\CIM\Downloads\deletefile.bat"
```

Comment: Look into Windows' Task Scheduler.

Comment: Using a programming language or which Operating System?

Comment: is it possible witour using task scheduler?

Comment: im using windows OS

Comment: By creating a .NET app using C# ...

Comment: @Carcigenicate pointed the right direction, the command is *schtasks /?*

Comment: @MaxMuster can you give me an example

Comment: I can but I do not have time now. Read the documentation : https://www.robvanderwoude.com/schtasks.php

Comment: Why would you want do to that without Scheduled task? It was designed for such situations and doesn't consume CPU unnecessarily like polling solutions

Answer (score -1):

```
if %DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2% EQU "20210408" (
    start "" "C:\Users\CIM\Downloads\deletefile.bat"
)
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to do that. it'll consume 100% CPU. At least sleep in each iteration or better use scheduled task

Comment: Besides it's highly fragile because `%date%` changes depending on system locale

Comment: Given the provided scenario/environment, my answer satisfies all requirements. No where in the code or the question is looping used or implied to be used, and the locale formatting matches the one in the question. Not trying to be rude, I just don't see why that warrants a down-vote when it directly answers the question.

Comment: it doesn't work as expected and doesn't answer the question. It runs the command an unknown number of times on that specific day, if the format `%date%` matches the format in the command. Imagine running deletefile.bat 80000 times in a day

Comment: The if() runs once. There is no looping in the question, or my answer. That's all from me - I've nothing else to add. Just to clarify, I do agree a scheduled task is the way to go. My answer was just answering the question as-asked.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately a single if block is useless to do run a task on a specific day